# Flawed collision detection between rectangles

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am creating a physics-based game with Pygame in which the player controls a ball. As you control the ball, it accelerates in the specified direction (holding the left arrow adds x pixels per frame to its movement speed). Since the ball is... well... a ball, and Pygame doesn't support ball collision detection, I created a new class with its own collision method. The method has two parts: if the ball runs into the corner of a rectangle, or if it runs into the side of the rectangle. The problem concerns the circle-to-side collision.

[image]

The ball is based on a rect object, and therefore has those pesky corners. I cannot use the simple `colliderect` method, otherwise the situation above would detect a collision where there should be none, and it would overlap the first part of my collision detection method. Instead, I opted to use `collidepoint` between the rectangle and the midpoints on each side of the ball's rectangle.

Finally, the heart of the issue. I mentioned earlier that the ball accelerates. When the ball accelerates to the point that (even though it appears to be standing still) it moves far enough into the rectangle for another midpoint on the circle to detect a "collision." This problem likely stems from the fact that (for a collision on the left side of the ball) my code sets the ball's `left` equal to the rectangle's `right`, so that when the ball accelerates enough to be inside the rectangle, it gets moved to another face of the rectangle.

Thank you so much for bearing with me, any and all suggestions are welcome. I would either be looking for a fix to my specific problem, or a cleaner way to handle the collision detection. My full code is below:

```
import pygame, sys, math

global Color
Color = {}
Color['white'] = (255,255,255)
Color['black'] = (  0,  0,  0)
Color['red']   = (255,  0,  0)
Color['green'] = (  0,255,  0)
Color['blue']  = (  0,  0,255)

global WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT
WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT = 500, 500

class Ball():
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, r, r)
        self.radius = r/2
        self.speed = [0, 0]
        self.b_fact = 1
        self.move = {'left':False, 'right':False, 'up':False, 'down':False}
        self.new_dir = {'left':False, 'right':False, 'up':False, 'down':False}

    def move_self(self):
        if self.move['left']:
            self.speed[0] -= 2
        if self.move['up']:
            self.speed[1] -= 2
        if self.move['right']:
            self.speed[0] += 2
        if self.move['down']:
            self.speed[1] += 2

        if self.speed[0] < 0:
            self.speed[0] += 1
        if self.speed[1] < 0:
            self.speed[1] += 1
        if self.speed[0] > 0:
            self.speed[0] -= 1
        if self.speed[1] > 0:
            self.speed[1] -= 1

        self.rect.left += self.speed[0]
        self.rect.top  += self.speed[1]

    def bounce(self, rectList):
        for rect in rectList:
            self.collide_rect(rect)
        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.new_dir['right'] = True
        if self.rect.right >=  WINDOWWIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WINDOWWIDTH
            self.new_dir['left'] = True
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
            self.new_dir['down'] = True
        if self.rect.bottom >=  WINDOWHEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = WINDOWHEIGHT
            self.new_dir['up'] = True

        for key in self.new_dir:
            if self.new_dir[key] and key=='left':
                self.speed[0] *= (-1)*self.b_fact
            if self.new_dir[key] and key=='right':
                self.speed[0] *= (-1)*self.b_fact
            if self.new_dir[key] and key=='up':
                self.speed[1] *= (-1)*self.b_fact
            if self.new_dir[key] and key=='down':
                self.speed[1] *= (-1)*self.b_fact
            self.new_dir[key] = False

    def collide_rect(self, rect):
        x1, y1, r = self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, self.radius
        foundSide = 0
        foundCorner = 0
        side_list = ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']
        corner_list = ['topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright']
        collision_list = []

        for side in side_list:
            if rect.collidepoint(eval('self.rect.mid'+side)):
                collision_list.append(side)

        for corner in corner_list:
            x2, y2 = eval('rect.'+corner)[0], eval('rect.'+corner)[1]
            dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
            if dist < r:
                if corner.find('left') > -1:
                    corner = corner.replace('left','right')
                else:
                    corner = corner.replace('right','left')
                if corner.find('top') > -1:
                    corner = corner.replace('top','bottom')
                else:
                    corner = corner.replace('bottom','top')
                collision_list.append(corner)

        for direction in collision_list:
            if direction.find('left') > -1:
                self.rect.left = rect.right
                self.new_dir['left'] = True
            if direction.find('top') > -1:
                self.rect.top = rect.bottom
                self.new_dir['top'] = True
            if direction.find('right') > -1:
                self.rect.right = rect.left
                self.new_dir['right'] = True
            if direction.find('bottom') > -1:
                self.rect.bottom = rect.top
                self.new_dir['bottom'] = True

class BallGame():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.display.set_caption("Ball is life")
        pygame.init()

        self.ball = Ball(0, 0, 30)

        self.allRects = []
        rect = pygame.Rect(60,60,50,50)
        self.allRects.append(rect)

        self.mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
        self.basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

    def drawScreen(self):
        self.screen.fill(Color['green'])
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.screen, Color['white'], self.ball.rect)
        for rect in self.allRects:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, Color['black'], rect)



    def mainloop(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            for i in range(2):
                k = (pygame.KEYUP, pygame.KEYDOWN)
                if event.type == k[i]:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.ball.move['left'] = i
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.ball.move['up'] = i
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.ball.move['right'] = i
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.ball.move['down'] = i

        self.ball.move_self()
        self.ball.bounce(self.allRects)

        self.drawScreen()

        pygame.display.update()
        self.mainClock.tick(20)

Game = BallGame()
while True:
    Game.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about the collision is to consider an enlarged version of the black rectangle. This would be a rounded rectangle with corner radius r. The collision between the ball and black rectangle is equivalent to the collision between the center of the ball and the rounded rectangle. This can help make the analysis of the situation easier.

When it bounces a more accurate way of determining the new position is to consider the line from the previous position to the current position. You can calculate where this line crosses the boundary and where a prefect reflection should be.

Comment: Do you have any ideas to handle the collision between the edges though? I can't use the basic `colliderect`, because as I mentioned earlier, it interferes with the already-functional corner-to-circle collision test.